# Set mesh coordinates offset of Freesurfer inflated

Tags: three.js, surface

I am trying to set an offset of x coordinates of inflated surfaces, left to 45 and right to -45. Now I have the following scene [image: following scene]

I am tried to add and suppose it should solve problem for right and left pials:

```
if (object.label == 'Right') {
            mesh.position.set( -2, 0, 0 );
          }
```

for dataInfo Right and Left files, but it returns `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'geometry.mesh.center')`

Here is the full [code](https://codeshare.io/5gjvzD) of loader:

Answer (score 0):

The line `geometry.mesh.center(45,0,0)` is definitely wrong since a geometry does not have a `mesh` property. I'm not sure what the code is supposed to do here but if you want to offset the vertices you should use [BufferGeometry.translate()](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/core/BufferGeometry.translate) instead:

```
geometry.translate( 45, 0, 0 );
```

`three.js R111`